# Is this a valid form of insertion sort?

Tags: perl, sorting, insertion-sort

Does the following code represent a valid implementation of *insertion sort*?

```
use warnings;

@arr = (5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3);
$size = @arr;
print "\nUnsorted array: @arr\n";

for ( $i = 1; $i < $size; $i++ ) {

    while ( $i > 0 && $arr[$i] < $arr[$i-1] ) {

        ($arr[$i], $arr[$i-1]) = ($arr[$i-1], $arr[$i]);
        $i--;
    }
}

print "Sorted Array:   @arr\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it needlessly revisits elements that have already been sorted. Fixed:

```
for my $i (1..#$arr) {
    my $j = $i;
    while ( $j > 0 && $arr[$j] < $arr[$j-1] ) {
        ($arr[$j], $arr[$j-1]) = ($arr[$j-1], $arr[$j]);
        $j--;
    }
}
```

I added `my $j = $i;`, and switched from `$i` to `$j` in the inner loop. The change to the for loop isn't a functional change; it's just cleaner and faster.

Now, the algorithm is identical to the first algorithm shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort).

Basically, think of `@arr` as two arrays. The leading elements form the sorted array, and the trailing elements form the unsorted array of elements to insert. `$i` is index of the first element of the unsorted elements, and the inner loop inserts `$arr[$i]` into the proper spot.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's identical to the first algorithm shown [*on Wikipedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)